# How to obtain a formula for kth powers of an integral.

Tags: calculus

I encountered a problem. When k=2, it is easy to calculate the result, but when k is greater than or equal to 3, I can’t figure it out. Could anyone can give me and idea or references that I can refer to. Thanks!

Here is the question:

If b(t) is integrable, then we have

$\left(\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\left|b(t)\right|^{2}dt\right)^{k}$
$=k!\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\int_{t_{1}}^{T_{2}}\int_{t_{2}}^{T_{2}}\cdots\int_{t_{k-2}}^{T_{2}}\int_{t_{k-1}}^{T_{2}}\left|b(t_{1})\right|^{2}\left|b(t_{2})\right|^{2}\times\cdots\times\left|b(t_{k-1})\right|^{2}\left|b(t_{t_{k}})\right|^{2}dt_{k}dt_{k-1}\cdots dt_{2}dt_{1}.$

For the case k=2,

$\left(\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\left|b(t)\right|^{2}dt\right)^{2} =\left(\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\left|b(t)\right|^{2}dt\right)\left(\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\left|b(s)\right|^{2}ds\right)
 =\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\left|b(t)\right|^{2}\left|b(s)\right|^{2}dsdt.$

Since the integrand $\left|b(t)\right|^{2}\left|b(s)\right|^{2}$ is symmetric, then

$\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\left|b(t)\right|^{2}\left|b(s)\right|^{2}dsdt =\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\int_{t}^{T_{2}}\left|b(t)\right|^{2}\left|b(s)\right|^{2}dsdt+\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\int_{s}^{T_{2}}\left|b(t)\right|^{2}\left|b(s)\right|^{2}dtds
 =2\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\int_{t}^{T_{2}}\left|b(t)\right|^{2}\left|b(s)\right|^{2}dsdt.$

Comment: I don't see any integral of $k^{\text{th}}$ powers but the $k^{\text{th}}$ power of an integral. And the bounds of the integrals in the last line seem... fanciful.

Comment: @ IAmAGuest title has been corrected. thanks~

Comment: What's the purpose of this computation ? The $k^{\text{th}}$ power of an expression is... its $k^{\text{th}}$ power.

Comment: the purpose of doing this transformation is to estimate the kth power. then we can estimate the exponent of the integral

Comment: Nonsense, whatever formula you will find will contain $k$ implicitly or explicitly.